# how to __add__ paths in python?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

I have the followong class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

class Path(object):
    "Docstring"

    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, path = ''):
        "docstring __init__"
        self.path=os.path.normpath(path)


    def __eq__(self, ruta):
        if self.path == ruta:
            return True  
        else:
            return False

    def __add__(self, other):
        return os.path.join(self, other)
```

I need to add two paths with **add**:
Path('/home/') + Path('pepe')

I have 2 problems:

1) How do I access the values ​​of both objects to add in the method **add**?
I have understood that a + b is like calling a.add (b) ...

2) in this code, returns me the following error:
 File "/home/esufan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 75, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.join()` accepts strings, not instances of your custom `Path` class. You need to access the `path` attribute of the two objects.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return os.path.join(self.path, other.path)
```

Comment: In that way, the result of the join is: 'pepe/pepe'
it's concatenating the same argument... :/

Comment: @eduardo.sufan That's because you have designated `__init__` as a `classmethod`, which you shouldn't do. Remove the `@classmethod` line and it'll work. (Classmethods operate on the class, so currently you're setting `path` on _all_ instances of `Path`.)